# How to interpret the distance of the Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, math, coordinates

I'm trying to develop an application which uses the ICP algorithm to find similarities between shapes drawn in a specific area, but I don't understand how to interpret the distance which I get at the end of it. This is the algorithm I used, starting only with a list of points: [image] where w is the rotation angle and T=(Tx, Ty) is the translation vector. They are described as well: [image] 
where: [image] Now, I tried to draw several shapes and what I was excepting is that the result would have been close to 0 if the shapes were very similar. Instead, with these shapes I got a final value of **3515.334**:[image] 
With this one I got **6615.08**: [image] 
And final, with this (they are completely different) I got **454.54**: [image] 
Did I misunderstood the algorithm?
This is the implementation:

```
   private void icp (int z, ArrayList<Pair<Float,Float>> points) {
        ArrayList<Pair<Float,Float>> copia = segments.get(z);
        ArrayList<Pair<Float,Float>> copia2 = points;
        double x_trattino = 0.0;
        double y_trattino = 0.0;
        double x_trattino_primo = 0.0;
        double y_trattino_primo = 0.0;
        for (int i=0; i<copia.size(); i++) {
            x_trattino+=copia.get(i).first;
            y_trattino+=copia.get(i).second;
        }
        x_trattino = x_trattino*((double)1/copia.size());
        y_trattino = y_trattino*((double)1/copia.size());
        for (int i=0; i<copia2.size(); i++) {
            x_trattino_primo+=copia2.get(i).first;
            y_trattino_primo+=copia2.get(i).second;
        }
        x_trattino_primo = x_trattino_primo*((double)1/copia2.size());
        y_trattino_primo = y_trattino_primo*((double)1/copia2.size());
        double Sxx = 0.0;
        double Syy = 0.0;
        double Sxy = 0.0;
        double Syx = 0.0;
        int min = 0;
        if (copia.size()>copia2.size()) min = copia2.size(); else min = copia.size();
        for (int i=0; i<min; i++) {
            Sxx+=((copia.get(i).first-x_trattino)*(copia2.get(i).first-x_trattino_primo));
        }
        for (int i=0; i<min; i++) {
            Syy+=((copia.get(i).second-y_trattino)*(copia2.get(i).second-y_trattino_primo));
        }
        for (int i=0; i<min; i++) {
            Sxy+=((copia.get(i).first-x_trattino)*(copia2.get(i).second-y_trattino_primo));
        }
        for (int i=0; i<min; i++) {
            Syx+=((copia.get(i).second-y_trattino)*(copia2.get(i).first-x_trattino_primo));
        }
        double rotation = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((Sxy-Syx)/(Sxx+Syy)));

        double Tx = x_trattino_primo - (x_trattino*Math.cos(rotation)-y_trattino*Math.sin(rotation));
        double Ty = y_trattino_primo - (x_trattino*Math.sin(rotation)+y_trattino*Math.cos(rotation));
        double eDist = 0.0;

        for (int i=0; i<min; i++) {
            eDist = (Math.pow(copia.get(i).first*Math.cos(rotation)-copia.get(i).second*Math.sin(rotation)+Tx-copia2.get(i).first, 2.0)+Math.pow(copia.get(i).first*Math.sin(rotation)+copia.get(i).second*Math.cos(rotation)+Ty-copia2.get(i).second, 2.0));
        }

        System.out.println("EDIST: "+eDist);
    }
```

Comment: You could check your output with that of an open-source implementation of the algorithm. It looks like you distance measure is partially a function of the raw number of points (in general, the more points, the greater the distance would be). It doesn't seem to be a direct similarity measure.

Comment: @JohnColeman What I did was to convert the algorithm into code, but I do not understand if it is checking the similarity between the shapes. What I can imagine looking at the result is: greater is the final result, more similar the shapes are. What do you thing about this?

Comment: Are you sure this is ICP? There doesn't seem to be any iteration of closest points here: you are simply assuming correspondence between the i-th points of the two shapes, and then aligning them, once. Shouldn't you be searching for the closest points, rather than assuming that correspondence is a-priori correct?

Comment: @AndyTurner I found out that this algorithm is used to check how similar two shapes are. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Fabio yes, it is finding the similarity between shapes, but that's not quite what ICP does. ICP finds the similarity between shapes with a-priori unknown correspondence. It proceeds by finding pairs of closest points between the shapes, *aligning them using your method*, them finding pairs of closest points again, aligning them again etc.

Comment: Also: do yourself a favour and write a `Point` class, so you can refer to `point.x` and `point.y`, rather than `point.first` and `point.second`. And use `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: Also also: the maths gets a lot easier if you are able to use singular value decomposition to calculate the rotation. I have used [JAMA](https://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) in the past.

Comment: @AndyTurner I read what the ICP algorithm does and maybe I'm thinking that it isn't what I'm excepting: I simply would return true or false if the shapes are similar or not The algorithm, instead, finds the optimal rotation and alignment to make the first shape to fit secondo one, which is a huge extra step I don't need (I guess).

Comment: @Fabio what you are doing here is [Procrustes analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis), not ICP (specifically, orthogonal Procrustes without scaling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mistakes you have made

1. Dont use Math.toDegrees, skip that call completely, the value in the variable rotation should be in radians not degrees.
2. You have written "eDist = ..." instead of "eDist += ...".
3. You have assumed that some "defining points" should match in the two different shapes. This is probably one of the biggest problems in the code. Lets say that you have two lines, the first is split in two parts while the other is not. Like this

   ```
   .--------.---------.
   .------------------.
   ```

   What you will try to compare are the shapes

   ```
   .--------.
   .------------------.
   ```

   These two shapes will not be similar and hence not give a small distance. This implies that you can have two shapes that look very similar but your algorithm will not detect this. To make a more complicated example of what you are trying to match is if you have several points lying like this in the two shapes

   ```
   p1--p2--p3----p4----------p5---p6
   q1------q2----------------q3---q4
   ```

   What you are trying to match is p1 to q1, p2 to q2, p3 to q3 and p4 to q4. This is obviously not satisfactory.

### One way forward

Choose one of the shapes as the source and the other as the target. For each source point, find the closest point in the target. Now you have a pair of points which are the matching points P and P' that you should use in the formulas. Note that several points in the source can be paired to the same point in the target. Repeat this process until there is not enough improvement in the error distance.

There are other ways of approaching ICP, and there are several problems that can occur. One problem to point out is that if you use the above approach on the line example I gave you, the error distance might not become small, since the middle point is not close to any point in the other shape.
So the above suggestion is not close the be exhaustive of what can be done, but at least I've given you a start.

Comment: Considering that my shapes are composed by only 1 segment (so the entire shape is in 1 ArrayList of points, since the user draws them with a single line), the problem explained above would not occur, right?

Comment: "Dont use Math.toDegrees" also, use `Math.atan2(y, x)` rather than `Math.atan(y/x)`

Comment: @Fabio I added an example to the answer, and I think the problem is still there.